# How do I make links from views to be opened in modal popups without adding custom rewrite?

Tags: views, modal-dialogs

I was trying to find if there is a way to avoid writing custom rewrite for links to open in modal popups from a view.

Here is what I am rewriting a custom field for doing this now.

```
<a href="url/{{ field_value }}" target="_blank" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options='{"width":"60%", "title":"Popup title"}'>View</a>
```

The problem with this approach is that this would require me to do it in multiple views with the same rewrite for each of the links that need to be opened in a popup.

Wanted to know if I can do this without the rewrite being added for every field.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions explicitly asking to recommend, find or compare a module, theme, distribution, or other off-site resource are off-topic for Drupal Answers.

Comment: Can you please direct as to how this question should have been asked? Or where else should I have asked this?

Comment: I went ahead and rewrote the question to specifically address the technical problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom field formatter that applies this, and then set that in the view instead of the manual rewrite. Either way, you are going to have to apply something to all of those links, no way to avoid setting that up initially.

Comment: Couldn't there be a plugin to add an option in the field edit popup where you can simply check a checkbox to say "Open link in popup"